# How do I automate load test in VSTS to run it during weekends?

Tags: load-testing

How do I automate load tests in VSTS?

I ran a load test in the cloud using VSTS, I would now like to automate it such that it runs every weekend.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Load Test Task which are build/release task which can be triggered by a scheduled build / release every weekend.

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/tasks/test/cloud-based-load-test

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/8337519/sheethal-j-s Thanks. I have web test plugins (Client secret ids). Does VSTS support plugins for automated test runs?